# EXTJs-Sorting fails to work when remortSort: true

Tags: sorting, extjs

I have a grid that I need to apply remote sorting. So my store look like this:

```
     $cls.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply({
            svc: this.svc,
            loadOnRender: false,
            remoteSort: true,
            directFn: this.svc.getData,
            cls: 'cls',
            storeConfig: {
                paramOrder : ['gridConfig'],
                sortInfo: {
                    field: 'date',
                    direction: 'DESC'
                }
            },
            fields: [{
                name: 'id'
            }
          },cfg));
```

When I set `remortSort: false`, the sorting works fine, but set to true, its not sorting properly. any ideas how does sorting work with `remortSort` set to true?
Thanks!

Comment: It will send a request to your server for the server to sort the data, however this doesn't look like a normal Ext scenario.

Comment: i understand now, but why does it have to fail to sort when remortSort is set to true?

Comment: What do you mean by "fail to sort"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable `remoteSort:true`, whenever someone tries to sort the grid, a request is sent to the server, where the [`sortParam`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Server.html#cfg-sortParam) contains information on how to sort the data. Then, the client expects to get the data, correctly sorted, from the server. There is no possibility to sort that data on client-side again, so your server-side code has to sort and return the data in correct order. The ExtJS store then only displays the data it gets from the server, in that very order.

This usually is used with paged grids, where not all data is available client-side, which is a common scenario in ExtJS when used for "Big Data" applications.

So, first, you have to check whether you really want to sort server-side, and then, you have to implement it there, using your existing server technology. In that case, your correct SO question would have to be: "How to sort data in <your server technology> before submitting it to the frontend as JSON." You should show the code where you access the data, because if you use SQL to get the data from a database, this is really easily done.